# An .mht file is displayed as text in IE9 on Windows 7

Tags: internet-explorer, plaintext, mhtml

I recorded an mht file using the Windows 7 psr.exe tool. When I double-click it, my IE displays the file contents "as is", i.e. as plain text. This is what I see at the top of the browser window:

```
From:
Subject:
Date:
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html";
  boundary="=_NextPart_SMP_1cdfe45348001c2_0003fd8b_00000001"
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
```

How to fix it? It happens only on one pc - other pc's in my LAN displays mht files correctly.

Comment: [This](http://filext.com/file-extension/MHT) might be helpful?

Comment: @Teemu, sure this does not help. It explains what is an mht file, but does not explain why the problem occurs.

Comment: It is associated with IE. Do I need something more? It should be viewed in IE.

Comment: "`Identify a program that can open the [.mht] file.`". Also there is an option in IE, with which you can choose if files are opened according to file extension or MIME-type.

Comment: And I do not understand why 2 points were deducted from my reputation for this question. This problem exists, I'm not the one who encountered it, and there is no clear solution in the web. At least, it cannot be found so easy.

Comment: Where to find this MIME option in IE9?

Comment: It's in Security settings, just before Popup-blocker option. Somebody has downvoted your question (before editing it was quite poor).

Comment: Do you mean the Internet options dialog, the Security tab? Cannot find it in my IE9, I have a Russian version of Windows. Can you give me a screenshot?

Comment: I've a Finnish version : ). Anyway, In "Internet options", "Security" tab is the 2nd tab from left, select "Intranet" (icon) and then click "Custom level" button, there's what you're looking for... (I hope my translations are correct.)

Comment: There was just 1 option related to MIME, and it was turned on. Toggled it, but this did not help.

Comment: I think the problem is in the proper registration of MHT and/or its MIME type in my system. Before I encountered my problem, I even could not open an mht by double-cliking - it was an unregistered file type. Is there a way to restore all default settings for this file type?

Comment: The registration problem was mentioned behind my link ; ). I just wish you good luck with this...

Answer (score 0):

I've found one interesting thread about this problem here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/does-internet-explorer-9-no-longer-support-mht/fa40b200-cef5-4670-87c4-3a32edbea5af.

It seems, MS Office installation may affect how mht files are viewed in IE. And as a quick workaround for this case, mht files can be opned properly in MS Word.